# Parse variables form json with bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have variables with JSON:

```bash
export RESPONSE=$(curl -s --request POST --data "$some_data" $some_url)
In RESPONSE
{
 "data": {
   "warnings": "1",
   "auth": "no"
  ... and a lot of variables
  }
}
```

And I need to create variables how it:

```bash
$warnings="1"
$auth="no"
....
```

I only need variables from the field `"data"`.

And in bash, as far as I understand, there is no `to_entries`.

And yet, I need that the data from #RESPONSE is not written to the console while the script is running.

**Update:**

I have this working code but it writes all JSON to console and that's not what I want.

```
export ENV_SETTER=$(for i in $KEYS; do echo -n env.$i=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r .data.$i),;done)
```

Next i need this

```
--set "${ENV_SETTER}"
```

Comment: `$RESPONSE={…` is not valid bash syntax to begin with. Please provide a [mre] (take the [tour], read [ask]).

Comment: And are you stuck with bash or with jq? With jq it should be as simple as `.data.warnings`. Please provide more details about the actual problem (again: a [mre] helps tremendously)

Comment: @LinFelix first answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq

Comment: And you want _all_ properties turned into variables or just warnings and auth? Even if they are called `PATH`, potentially wreaking havoc? How trusted is the data? Why do you have to use variables and not use command substitution where the value is required? Asked differently: what do you gain by putting those values in distinct variables?

Comment: `to_entries` is not part of bash but part of jq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using jq to assign multiple output variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291389/using-jq-to-assign-multiple-output-variables)

Comment: @knittl all properties to variables. Data is secure. I am Update question, check please.

Comment: @LinFelix
Ok, ty. When i try to use this, i get this:
/bin/bash: line 196: to_entries: command not found

Comment: Show us line 196.

Comment: @glennjackman, I am try this:

1. `echo RESPONSE | jq -r '.data | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)'`

2. `echo RESPONSE | jq -r .data | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)`

3. `echo RESPONSE | jq -r .data | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value`

4. `echo RESPONSE | jq -r .data | to_entries`

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting to put the jq code in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dangerous to set variables the way you want to.
Already existing variables with the same name will be overwritten and this can damage your environment. Think about this security vulnerability beforehand.

I come up with two solutions

1. using `eval`
2. avoiding `eval`

### Solution 1

```bash
eval $(jq -r '.data | to_entries | map("export " + .key + "='"'"'" + .value + "'"'"'")[]' "$FILE")
```

`eval` executes the code generated by `jq`:

```
export warnings='1'
export auth='no'
```

**Remark**

- the cryptic `'"'"'"` is not `jq` syntax. It is a way to add single quotes to a string in bash

### Solution 2

```bash
RESPONSE='
{
  "data": {
    "warnings": "1",
    "auth": "no"
  }
}
'

KEYS=$(jq -r '.data | keys[]' <<< "$RESPONSE")
for KEY in $KEYS; do
  VALUE=$(jq -r --arg key "$KEY" '.data | .[$key]' <<< "$RESPONSE")
  read "$KEY" <<< "$VALUE"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, but eval is not way to me

Comment: I have added a second solution that avoids `eval`.

Comment: Thank you. But solution 2 is not way to me too, because 
1. My json not in file
2. On each iteration to console wrote all file. My json very big and it turns, what these records are logged and very large logs are obtained

Comment: It is easy to change the input from a file to a string. I have edited solution 2 for you. On my computer nothing is written to the console